# How to create three bar charts in grouped and line chart combined in TABLEAU

Tags: tableau-api

This is the sample data to create that graph in tableau?

X,bar1,bar2,bar3,forline

Jan,157,942,1099,17%

Feb,172,1189,1365,14%

Comment: this is the link to sample graph in plotly                                                                                                        https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipOEG3y3TyGu7uu2nm2wWKcsztQgYR9g2-mziYUfpPu8Ol2Zmq2i7_yDZLZSZNcHFg?key=S0U0eWI1WFhQRGxyM0VGMzhMWDZZZjlSczV0eUd3

Comment: All you need is a combo chart with bar1, bar2, bar2 sticking to one axis, and line on the other axis. Then you have to right-click on-axis and synchronize them.

Comment: can you please share the link to twbx with the data I provided it would be greater help for me.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by creating a dual axis chart between the Line field and Measure Values, and adding the Measure Names to the filter pane to select Bar1, Bar2, Bar3.
Hope the below link helps:
https://public.tableau.com/profile/arunima4660#!/vizhome/SO_Ans/Sheet1

Comment: That is not correct I do not want months at the top I need that at the bottom and second, that line is a graph is not correct.                               See this https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipOEG3y3TyGu7uu2nm2wWKcsztQgYR9g2-mziYUfpPu8Ol2Zmq2i7_yDZLZSZNcHFg?key=S0U0eWI1WFhQRGxyM0VGMzhMWDZZZjlSczV0eUd3